# Почему YouTube API выдает ошибку YT is not defined?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

Мой js выглядит так:

```
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'ZF_1vqGZgw0',
            events: {
             'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }

    onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
```

в разметке:

```
<div class="slide" id="ytplayer"></div>
```

Браузер выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined
```

***Что я делаю не так???***

Решил проблему, код с решенной пробелмой прикрепляю снизу.

**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loadPlayer() {
        if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
                onYouTubePlayer();
            };
        }
    }

    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayer() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'ZF_1vqGZgw0',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }



    $(function () {
        loadPlayer();
    })
});
```

Comment: А где `<script>`, который загружает библиотеку YT?

Comment: @gil9red первые три строчки разве не то, что вы спрашиваете? Он уменя добавлен через js в `<head>`

Comment: Виноват, посмотрите, тут ваша проблема и ее решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065032/

Comment: @gil9red Посмотрите пожалуйста код, я добавил текущий вариант. При вызове onYouTubePlayer браузер выдает ошибку : `onYouTubePlayer is not defined
    at window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`

Comment: @gil9red если не вызывать, то и ошибки нет.

Comment: @gil9red скиньте ссылку в Ответы чтобы я вас отметил , как подходящий ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: Добавил. Вы не против, что я ваш код использовал для ответа?

Comment: @gil9red конечно нет!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решению проблемы помог [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31111115/5909792).

Адаптированный автором вопрос код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function loadPlayer() {
        if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
                onYouTubePlayer();
            };
        }
    }

    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayer() {
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '360',
            width: '640',
            videoId: 'ZF_1vqGZgw0',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    loadPlayer();
});
```

Comment: Зачем делать 2-ную проверку, на загрузку документа?

Comment: @And, вы правы, исправил

Comment: @gil9red скажите пожалуйста, я еще пытаюсь сделать такую логику - при клике на видео сразу воспроизводить его в fullscreen, возможно ли такое реализовать на youtube api ?

Comment: @RafaelShepard, не знаю. Попробуйте https://codepen.io/kyokid/pen/egQgzW функция `function playFullscreen (){`